# web.crypto encryption c# decryption

Tags: javascript, c#, cryptography, aes, webcrypto-api

I'm trying to do:

1. encrypt text using web.crypto,
2. decrypt text using AesCryptoServiceProvider 
   I didn't get any exceptions in my code, but the decryption doesn't match the plain text that i've encrypted

**the plaintext bytes after decyption are the same, but the encoding to string doesn't work**

I'm using random iv, the key and the plaintext are constant.

```
function cryptoSys(plaintext,KeyString){
        var iVec=window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));                        
        var encryptSuccessFunc=(encrypt)=> { AfterEncrypt(BytearrayToString(iVec),arraybufferTostring(encrypt));}
        var ImportKeySuccessFunc= (keyObj)=>{                  
                                  window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(                
                                   {name:"AES-CBC", iv:iVec},
                                   keyObj,
                                  StringToByteArray(plaintext)
                                   ).then(encryptSuccessFunc);           

         window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
            "raw", 
            StringToByteArray(KeyString),
            {name:"AES-CBC", length:128},
            true,
            ["encrypt","decrypt"]
            ).then(ImportKeySuccessFunc);
}
```

After that I'm sending the iVec, ciphertext using json

```
 function AfterEncrypt(iVec,ciphertext)
    {            
        var plaintext="String to Encrypt";
        if(iVec==null)
            return;
        var send2server= {"ciphertext":ciphertext,
            "iVec":iVec,
            "plaintext":plaintext};            
        var objectDataString = JSON.stringify(send2server);            
        sendJSONtoserver(objectDataString,"getDelayedBid");                  
    }
```

I'm using the following utility functions :

```
    function StringToByteArray(strString) {            

        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(strString.length);
        for (var i=0; i<strString.length; i++) {
            byteArray[i] = strString.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return byteArray;
    }
    function BytearrayToString(arrayBuffer) {            
        var strString = "";                        
        for (var i=0; i<arrayBuffer.byteLength; i++) {                
            strString += String.fromCharCode(arrayBuffer[i]);
        }
        return strString;
    }
     function arraybufferTostring(buf) {
        return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buf));
    }
```

server side accepts the keys, and suppose to decrypt:

```
public string DecryptCipher(Encoding u16, string cipherText, string key,string iVec)
    {
        byte[] ciphertextBytes = clearZeros(u16.GetBytes(cipherText)); 
        AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        aes.BlockSize = 128;
        aes.KeySize = 128; //minimun key length
        aes.Key = clearZeros(u16.GetBytes(key)); 
        aes.IV = clearZeros(u16.GetBytes(iVec));
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        ICryptoTransform cryptoTrans = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
        byte[] plaintextBytes = cryptoTrans.TransformFinalBlock(ciphertextBytes, 0, ciphertextBytes.Length);
        cryptoTrans.Dispose();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(plaintextBytes);
    }
```

I've got this utility function as well:

```
private byte [] clearZeros(byte [] bytearray)
    {
        byte[] ans = new byte[bytearray.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < bytearray.Length / 2; i++)
            ans[i] = bytearray[2 * i];
        return ans;
    }
```

I'm getting the paramters from anthor function:

```
public ActionResult getDelayedBid([FromBody] DelayedSubmission delaySub)
    {
        if (delaySub.ciphertext == null)
            return Json("Failure", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        Encoding u16LE = Encoding.Unicode;        
        String decrypetedMessageLE = new Encryption().DecryptCipher(u16LE, delaySub.ciphertext,  getKeyFromDB(), delaySub.iVec);                
        if (decrypetedMessageLE.Equals(delaySub.plaintext) )
            {
                return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        return Json("Failure", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used wrong Ecoding,
instand of

Convert.ToBase64String(plaintextBytes);

I should've used

Encoding.ASCII.GetString(plaintextBytes);